# Only show selected traces when first plotting with drop down plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to use drop downs to change data. When the plot is first generated, all 4 traces show on the plot, even though I have it set to only show two. When I switch to the second drop down option, it plots correctly. When I then switch back to the first drop down option, it also plots correctly. How do I fix it to plot properly when first loaded?

```
time1=pd.date_range((today-dt.timedelta(days=5)), (today+dt.timedelta(days=10)), freq='6H')
time2=pd.date_range((today-dt.timedelta(days=5)), (today+dt.timedelta(days=9)), freq='D')

data1=np.random.randint(low=65,high=85, size=61)
data2=np.random.randint(low=-2,high=2, size=15)

data3=np.random.randint(low=65,high=85, size=61)
data4=np.random.randint(low=-2,high=2, size=15)

trace1=go.Scatter(x=time1, y=data1 ,mode='lines', line=dict(color='red', width=4), yaxis='y1')
trace2=go.Bar(x=time2, y=data2, marker_color='black', opacity=0.6, yaxis='y2')

trace3=go.Scatter(x=time1, y=data3,mode='lines', line=dict(color='red', width=4), yaxis='y1') 
trace4=go.Bar(x=time2, y=data4, marker_color='black', opacity=0.6, yaxis='y2')



data=[trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4]


updatemenus=[{'buttons': [{'method': 'update',
                                 'label': 'data1',
                                 'args': [{'visible': [True, True, False, False]},]
                                  },
                                {'method': 'update',
                                 'label':'data2',
                                 'args': [{'visible': [False, False, True, True]},]}],
                   'direction': 'down',
                   'showactive': False,}]

layout = go.Layout(updatemenus=updatemenus, yaxis2=dict(overlaying='y', side='right'))
go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
```

First load:

[image: first load]

Second load:

[image: second load]

Third load of first dropdown option:

[image: third load]